# flex-shrink not working on <img> in vertical (column) flexbox container

Tags: css, image, layout, flexbox

The beauty of the `<img>`-tag is that it occupies layout vertically based on its aspect ratio when you only set a width. Cool!

Now I want the image to do and behave just like that, **until there is no more room vertically**.
And as to my understanding `flex-shrink` does exactly that.

In the following codepen the `.flexbox`s height is hardcoded to simulate a height restrction (in my project this would be another flex-container in a full-height viewport scenario)
https://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/RwrWorr

Now why does the image not shrink below on a aspect ratio greater than 1.85 – it's easier to debug it here: https://cdpn.io/katerlouis/debug/RwrWorr/dGMXWKBbVKnk – use the responsive resizing in devtools to change the viewport for instance to 770x415 and decrease the height of the viewport to see it won't shrink.

To make things more clear: Here is what happens for a viewport of 770x300
[image]

And here's the desired outcome.
[image]

I would maaaybe understand if this is just not possible because no css code controls the height of the image? but why does `flex-grow` work then?

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue. Also, the second link show "This debug view expired". Maybe create a screenshot of the `current output` VS `desired result`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the confusion. I updated the original question.